# in javascript, difference input.value=val versus input.setAttribute('value',val)?

Tags: javascript, dom, attributes, properties

In javascript, is what is the difference between setting an HTMLElement property with assignment as versus using `setAttribute()`.  The following is from a chrome session, leading me to believe there *is* a difference:

```
> i = document.createElement('input');
<input>
> i.value = 'abc';
"abc"
> i
<input>​
> i.setAttribute('value','abc');
undefined
> i
<input value=​"abc">
```

What exactly is the difference?  Is it the type of thing that bytes you in the ass?

---

answer right on.

chrome displays attributes, so this led to my confusion.

Comment: Although the question is about jQuery, the answer can be applied here too: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5874652/prop-vs-attr

Comment: The reason you see the `undefined`" here is merely that that is what element.setAttribute() returns as a value. The line above `i.value = 'abc';` prints `"abc"` simply because that is the value of the assignment expression. Neither output has anything to do with what actually happened to the DOM.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> In javascript, is what is the difference between setting an HTMLElement property with assignment as versus using setAttribute()

It depends on the property.

The value property reflects the *current* value, the value attribute reflects the *default* value.

Some properties map directly onto attributes.

Comment: are you implying that if only setAttribute() is used, when `input` is rendered, there would be no `value`?

Comment: on further testing, "default" is absolutely the correct description.  if setAttribute, will set `value` if and only if `value` is undefined.